# Element Changes when another it transformed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've encountered a strange behavior that maybe a bug in Chrome.

The issue is that when I animate the gallery transform property, an image below looses it's border radius ?! Here's the full website on my test server:
http://chelefoto.com.192-198-106-143.vanilla.websavers.ca/

```html
<div class="headshot">
  <img src="img/moi.jpg">
</div>
```

Here's an example of how I'm animating the gallery:

```js
$('.arrow-container.right').click(function(){
                    var i = $('.arrow-container.right').index($(this));
                    divScroll[i].pos -= scrollSpeed;

                    // prevent scrolling past width of gallery //
                    if (divScroll[i].pos <= -(divScroll[i].width - galleryWidth) ){
                        divScroll[i].pos = -(divScroll[i].width - galleryWidth);
                    }
                    var container = $(this).siblings('.gallery-scroll').children('.gallery-container');
                    container[0].style.transform = "translate3d("+ divScroll[i].pos +"px,0, 0)";
                });
```

```html
<div id="wedding-gallery" class="gallery">
  <div class="arrow-container left">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-container right">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-scroll">
    <div class="gallery-container" style="width: 2000px;">
      <img class="tile" src="img/galleries/wedding-1.jpg">
      <img class="tile" src="img/galleries/wedding-2.jpg">
      <img class="tile" src="img/galleries/wedding-3.jpg">
      <img class="tile" src="img/galleries/wedding-4.jpg">
      <img class="tile" src="img/galleries/wedding-5.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This happens even if I change the transform value in the dev tools of Chrome.

This does not happen in IE or FireFox. I think it is a Chrome bug, but I thought I'd check with the community here to see if anyone can see a reason in my code for this behaviour.

Comment: Please include a clean, functional, minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using updated version of Google Chrome. If you are using 4.0 version of Google Chrome then here is the correct syntax for using border-radius.

```
-webkit-border-radius:5px
```

If you are using updated version then it should not be a problem. Just simply use

```
border-radius:5px
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome 41.0.2272.53 beta-m (64-bit), also happened on Chrome for Android (not sure of the version number) and Chrome 40

Comment: Can you tell me exactly which border is causing problem and not getting displayed? Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: in the .head-shot div . It is the first image under the galleries in the full website. As soon as the any gallery element has it's transform property changed, the border disappears.

Comment: are you talking about this one? http://geekfellows.com/help.jpg   Everything works fine for me.